# Windows vista, IIS7 and error messages/pages

Tags: windows-vista, iis-7

I have a new laptop installed with Windows Vista Ultimate (Swedish version). I changed the display language to English - everything seems okay except error pages in IIS7 are still in Swedish.

Is it possible to get error pages/messages in English?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to edit the language tag in the "Edit Customer Error Page"

More detailed info is available here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/webtopics/archive/2008/05/28/iis-7-0-http-error-pages.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that the UI language is per account. This means that switching the language for your user account will not have any effect on IIS since it runs under another account.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issues with IIS logging using US date formats when the default system language was mis-selected.  Unfortunately, the only solution there was to reinstall and make sure I got the correct language during setup (this was on 2003).  Not much help I'm afraid...